# shortcode not comging through on wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, anythingslider

so I'm using this awesome plugin "anything slider" and have successfully integrated into the template. however, it's bringing in all slides instead of just a category. This is the shortcode I'm using... which brings in all slides...

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[anything_slides cat="ur"]" ); ?>
```

The shortcode to bring in a category works within the wysiqyg editor like this:

[anything_slides cat="ur"]

Can someone possibly help?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/anythingslider-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the "double-quote" have to be escaped:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[anything_slides cat=\"ur\"]" ); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[anything_slides cat="ur"]' ); ?>
```

Hope it helps!